# How to store string value in javascript after input from textbox

Tags: javascript, parsing, button, token, getelementbyid

New javascript programmer here. I am attempting to create a "goal manager" web app that takes in text input from the user

```
      return (
    <>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <StyledH1>Strengthen and stay on top of your goals</StyledH1>
      
      <input id = "text1" placeholder = "New Goal: "/>
  
      <button onclick= "fn1()" id = "btn1"> Set Goal </button>
     
      <script>
        function fn1 () {
        var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        alert("Value: " + str);
      }
      </script>
      
      {goals.map((goal) => (
        <Goal
          key={goal.id}
          goal={goal}
          updates={updates.filter(
            (update) => update.fields.goalid[0] === goal.id
          )}
        />
      ))}
    </>
  );
}
```

I attempted to store the value inputted using the code above, but I run into the error "Parsing error: Unexpected token" pointing to var. This code is inside of return () in my App.js file.

When I try to put my fn1() outside of return(), the code compiles, but then I get the warning "'fn1' is defined but never used  " and the code fails to work, yet there are no more issues with var.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: put your code in a script tag https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_script.asp

Comment: where, inside the return ()? I did so but am still getting the unexpected token error

Comment: I don't see a `return()` in your code...

Comment: sorry, I just updated the code to reflect the bigger picture of what was happening!

Comment: It looks like you are mixing javascript and html together. Your html (<input> <button>) etc. should not reside inside of your javascript.

Comment: I thought I was following a javascript tutorial though? https://youtu.be/lThuZY0-S_8 How do I separate the two? Sorry for all the questions and thank you for your patience :)

Comment: I have provided an answer below that I hopes help clarifies things.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. The javascript code should be written in the script tag.

```html
 <input id = "text1" placeholder = "New Goal: "/>
    
     <button onclick= "fn1()" id = "btn1"> Set Goal </button>
      
    <script>
      function fn1 () {
        var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
        alert("Value: " + str);
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: should this be inside the return()? I'm still getting the unexpected token error

Answer (score 0):

The basic problem is you are trying to mix html and javascript in your app.js file. Please find an example below of how to separate javascript and html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      /* This is script and is not mixed with html
         it could also be referred to from a separate file e.g. app.js */
      <script>
         function fn1 () {
           var str = document.getElementById("text1").value;
           alert("Value: " + str);
         }
      </script>
   </head>
   /* This is html and is not mixed with javascript */
   <body>
      <input id = "text1" placeholder = "New Goal: "/>
      <button onclick= "fn1()" id = "btn1"> Set Goal </button>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification between html/javascript! I'm still getting the "Parsing error: Unexpected token" error though :/ is there something wrong with var? It doesnt work when I use const or String either

Comment: It's hard to say. I think you need to post another example with all of the revised code.